# Group by with average in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

In file Census.json I have data as below:

```
[
    {
        "savingsBalance": "$16,264.00",
        "age": 38,
        "firstname": "Carmella",
        "lastname": "Mcguire",
        "gender": "female",
        "company": "Vicon",
        "email": "carmellamcguire@vicon.com",
        "phone": "+1 (877) 400-3279",
        "city": "Fresno",
        "state": "Minnesota"
    },
    {
        "savingsBalance": "$10,228.00",
        "age": 30,
        "firstname": "Ollie",
        "lastname": "Wolfe",
        "gender": "female",
        "company": "Kengen",
        "email": "olliewolfe@kengen.com",
        "phone": "+1 (934) 564-2156",
        "city": "Felt",
        "state": "Tennessee"
    }
]
```

Of course, in file, there is much more of them.
I would like group it by savingsBalance. What I am doing:

firstly I load data from file:

```
var jsonStringCensus = File.ReadAllText("C:\\...\\Census.json");
```

Then I have to deserialize it:

```
var censuses = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Census>>(jsonStringCensus);
```

I can print it into console:

```
var data = censuses.Select(x => string.Format("{0} {1}" ,x.state, x.savingsBalance.Substring(1)));
var dataPrintable = averageSavingBalancePerState.Select(x => string.Format("{0} {1}", x.Key));

Console.WriteLine(dataPrintable);
```

And finally, I would like group it by state and print average savingsBalances:

```
var dataDouble =
            from w in censuses
            group w by w.state into g
            select new { GState = g.Key, Average = g.Average(p => { double a; a = Convert.ToDouble(p.savingsBalance); return a; }) };


    foreach (var g in dataDouble)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The state '{0}':", g.GState);
        foreach (var w in g.Average.ToString())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(w);
        }
    }
```

I don't have any errors and it is compiles.But when programm is executed I have exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format. The exception appear before line 

select new { GState = g.Key, Average = g.Average(p => { double a; a = Convert.ToDouble(p.savingsBalance); return a; }) };
```

Do you have any idea why should I do to get correct result? Thanks in advance

Comment: `"$16,264.00"` is a currency format, not plain double

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Double.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7yd1h1be%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (or `Decimal.Parse` as Timothy suggests) to parse double from string in currency style:

```
from c in censuses
group c by c.state into g
select new { 
  GState = g.Key, 
  Average = g.Average(c => Double.Parse(c.savingsBalance, NumberStyles.Currency))
}
```

Comment: Could suggest `decimal.Parse` as well since money amounts are involved.

Comment: @TimothyShields very good suggestion. Agree with you - decimal is more appropriate type for money

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't solve my problem. I used Double.Parse and Decimal.Parse. It doesn't work and throws the same exception... I am really so frustrated...

Comment: @Tomek what is currency symbol on your machine? It's returned by `NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.CurrencySymbol`

Comment: @Tomek you can provide US culture if all currencies are in USD `Double.Parse(s, NumberStyles.Currency, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"))`

Comment: @Sergey Berezovskiy my currency is PLN (Polish). As you wrote I try NumberStyles.Currency, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")). Now it works and give me correct data. Thanks for all for help!